# What to do about this long error: This application is trying to draw a very large combo box

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, nscombobox

I cannot find any reference to this on SO.. The full message is:

> "This application is trying to draw a very large combo box, 32 points
>   tall.  Vertically resizable combo boxes are not supported, but it
>   happens that 10.4 and previous drew something that looked kind of sort
>   of okay.  The art in 10.5 does not break up in a way that supports
>   that drawing.  To avoid breaking existing apps, NSComboBox in 10.5
>   will use the 10.4 art for large combo boxes, but it won't exactly
>   match the rest of the system.  This application should be revised to
>   stop using large combo boxes.  This warning will appear once per app
>   launch."

Any ideas what to do about it?

I made the box in IB, and don't think I did anything special to create it.

Comment: what happens if you make the height of your combo box smaller, just for testing purposes?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I actually don't see a way to adjust the height. I'm probably missing something dumb.

Comment: I did try this: [comboBox setItemHeight:30]; but no joy. The height was not changed, and I don't know what else to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. When I dragged comboboxes out of a Stack View, Xcode messed up their heights. To correct the problem, I added height constraints of 22 to each of them. That caused the warning. When I deleted all the height constraints, the warning went away. The comboboxes didn't revert to the crazy heights they had when I dragged them out.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.  The combo box was in a cell in a table.  I changed the row height setting of the table to automatic.  But, this gave me an error for not being a valid setting for a cell based table.  However, when I reset the table's row height to fixed, the message went away.

More Google searches seem to indicate that this has something to do with the height of the combo box.  In my case, the row height of the table increased when I reset it from "Automatic".  Perhaps this will give you something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this forever, but ignored it because I had no idea why it was happening.
From reading the other answers here...

[image]

From the storyboard I edited the Combo Box Cell inside the combo box. I changed the Cell Size from Regular to Small and back to Regular.
The problem went away.